# Preserve vertex and edge labels while merging graphs in mathematica

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

I am looking for the connected component of two graphs that include the vertex labelled "9". From the code below, I do have what I want, but it is missing the labels I put in my original graphs!

```
degree = 1000;
WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[
 GraphUnion[
  Graph[(# \[DirectedEdge] Power[#, 2]) & /@ (Range[degree]*9), 
   EdgeLabels -> 2, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  Graph[(# \[DirectedEdge] Power[#, 3]) & /@ (Range[degree]*9), 
   EdgeLabels -> 3, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], 9, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

This part:

```
Graph[(# \[DirectedEdge] Power[#, 2]) & /@ (Range[degree]*9), 
   EdgeLabels -> 2, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

gives me a graph with all the edges labelled "2"

This part:

```
Graph[(# \[DirectedEdge] Power[#, 3]) & /@ (Range[degree]*9), 
   EdgeLabels -> 3, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

gives me a graph with all the edges labelled "3".

But the final connected component does not have those edge labels, which means that it's hard for me to tell which graph it came from. Is there a way for me to merge these graphs while preserving the original labels?